# Outlook - forms and surveys with a twist

Tags: forms, outlook

I'm trying to find a way to create a survey-type of form within outlook so that we can send **individualised** forms to a number of users.

Here is the longer version. We have identified a large number of reports within a very large commercial system that get run every month by applications administrators. We have identified the people who are the "targets" for these reports. What we would like to do is to send out a "form" for each of the reports to the targeted person to find out if they use the data on the report, what format they would prefer etc.

I know we can do survey type polls in Outlook but I'm not sure about individual survey for a large number of subjects (they are some 100+ reports we are dealing with).

Have searched the net but everything I see is very generalised.

Would anyone care to offer a suggestion as to whether nor not this is possible using Outlook (large organisation, geographically dispersed) and/or a better solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two main ways to go:

1. Develop Outlook custom forms. See [Customizing Outlook Message Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=61) for more information.
2. Develop an add-in for Outlook which should be installed on both sides. In that case the sender can add user properties to the message. The add-in on the recipient side can use these values to display on the custom form. For example, you may use an Outlook form region to display the information. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.